# How to make synchronous db query before asynchronous node app starts?

Tags: node.js, cors

I run node app with CORS. 
Currently I load whitelisted domains from .env file but I need to change it to load them from database. The whole CORS functionality is synchronous and I wonder what's the proper way to make db query for it.

app.js

```
app.use(cors());

async function listenCallback(server) {
try {
    // app code
} catch (err) {
    server.close();
}
```

cors.js

```
const cors = require('cors');
const db = require('../db');


const whitelist = db.raw('select domains from table'); // I need to change this


module.exports = (enabled = true) =>
    (req, res, next) => {
        const options = {
            origin(origin, callback) {
                if (!origin) {
                    callback(null, true);
                    return;
                }
                const originIsWhitelisted = enabled ? whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 : true;
                if (originIsWhitelisted) {
                    callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
                    return;
                }
                callback({
                    statusCode: 401,
                    error: 'Not allowed',
                });
            },
        };
        return cors(options)(req, res, next);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is to load a set of domains from a database upon module initialization so you can then use those in some middleware, then you can get a promise from loading the whilelist from the database and then just use that promise in your middleware.

```
const cors = require('cors');
const db = require('../db');

const whitelistPromise = db.someOperationThatReturnsPromise();

module.exports = (enabled = true) =>
    (req, res, next) => {
        const options = {
            origin(origin, callback) {
                if (!origin) {
                    callback(null, true);
                    return;
                }
                whitelistPromise.then(whitelist => {
                    const originIsWhitelisted = enabled ? whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 : true;
                    if (originIsWhitelisted) {
                        callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
                        return;
                    }
                    callback({
                        statusCode: 401,
                        error: 'Not allowed',
                    });
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    next(err);
                    return;
                });
            },
        };
        return cors(options)(req, res, next);
    };
```

---

Another approach is to export a module constructor function from the module that returns a promise that tells your server when your module initialization is done and provides this middleware function as the resolved value.  I like this approach better because if the db operation fails, you will know it more centrally and can provide better error handling.

```
const cors = require('cors');
const db = require('../db');

// export module constructor that initializes this module asynchronously and returns a promise
// That promise resolves to the middleware function (so it can't be used before
// the module is properly initialized)
module.exports = function() {
    return db.someOperationThatReturnsPromise().then(whitelist => {
        return (enabled = true) => (req, res, next) => {
            const options = {
                origin(origin, callback) {
                    if (!origin) {
                        callback(null, true);
                        return;
                    }
                    const originIsWhitelisted = enabled ? whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 : true;
                    if (originIsWhitelisted) {
                        callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
                        return;
                    }
                    callback({
                        statusCode: 401,
                        error: 'Not allowed',
                    });
                },
            };
            return cors(options)(req, res, next);
        };
    });
}
```

In this case, whoever loads this module will do it something like this:

```
require('./myModule')().then(makeWhitelistMiddleware => {
    // put route handlers here that use the function to make CORS middleware
    // don't start your server until this completes
    app.use(makeWhitelistMiddleware());
    // other routes here
    app.get(...)
    // start server
    app.listen(...);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Could not initialize myModule");
    process.exit(1);
});
```

---

Lastly, I'll add that there is effort underway to allow top level `await` inside of module initialization where the whole module loader system can be made aware of promises involved in initializing a module.  That type of capability would make this a lot simpler, but until then you have to add your own custom code to initialize the module differently and load the module differently.

Comment: I tried first approach but it only works for the first call, in the next ones whitelist gets empty.

Comment: @jokuja - Then, you're doing something different than I proposed.  You can call `somePromise.then()` as many times as you want and get the same data every time.  Promises latch their resolved data and store it forever (for the lifetime of the promise).  I would have to see the actual code you tried in order to know how to help.

Comment: I got it, I was doing some wrong magic over whitelist. Works perfect, thanks!

Comment: @jokuja - Cool.  Glad you figured it out.